# Dynamically created check box doesn't get checked on button click in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

1. I create a check box dynamically (based on condition) on "create checkbox" button and added this checkbox in panel.
2. According to my condition, Only 1 checkbox will be added in panel and it's item id will be "a1".
3. When click on another button "checkedcheckbox" checkbox should be checked but it doesn't. When i get this checkbox by itemid on button click, then it show undefined in developer tools. If i get it by panel items then it doesn't show undefine but checkbox doesn't checked.

**PROBLEM**

1. Why checkbox show undefined if i get it by itemId ?
2. Why Checkbox is not checked if i am getting by panel items. It should be get in both ways by getting directly through itemid and panel items.

There is some problem on my account in sencha fiddler, that's why i can create a fiddler for you.

Code

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
            var window = new Ext.Window({
                id: 'grdWindow',
                width: 400,
                height: 500,
                title: 'Grid Samples',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Create checkbox',
                        handler: function () {

                            var obj1 = [
                                { a: 1},
                                { a: 2},
                                { a: 3},
                                { a: 4}
                            ];

                            var obj2 = [
                                { a: 1 },
                                { a: 5 }
                            ];

                            var i = 1;
                            var panel = Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting');
                            Ext.each(obj1, function (ob1) {
                                Ext.each(obj2, function (ob2) {
                                    if (ob1.a == ob2.a) {
                                        panel.add({
                                            items:[
                                                {
                                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                                    itemId: 'a'+i
                                                }
                                                ]
                                        });
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                });
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        id: 'pnlTesting',
                        height: 100,
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'checkedcheckbox',
                        handler: function () {

                            Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting').items.items[0].items.items[0].checked = true;

                            //Ext.getCmp("a1").checked = true;
                            //Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting').doLayout();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }).show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to change the state of the checkbox you should do it with `setValue(true)` and not `checked=true`.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'checkedcheckbox',
    handler: function (btn) {
        Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting').items.items[0].items.items[0].setValue(true);                          
    }
}
```

And also, that's an ugly way of getting the component, i get it with `down()` and its `itemId`

```
Ext.getCmp('pnlTesting').down('#a1').setValue(true);
```

P.D: You should improve this selector because using `id` and `getCmp()` is not a good practice for ExtJS.

Comment: Yes. Now it works. It should be setValue(true) instead of checked = true. But checked=true also works. I used it many times. Don't why it doesn't work here. Can you tell me reason if you know.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend learning the usage of `.up()` `.down()` `.prev()`, `.next()` and `.query()`

They are powerful tools to navigate through every component in your object structure without dealing with special item ids. You can also fetch components via config options like `component.query('button[name="mybutton"]')`

I made a (very) small example for your requirement in sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sii

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. There was mistake in checked=true. I have to use setValue(true) and it works. But sometime i used checked=true and it works. Don't know why it's not working here. Can you tell me if you know.

Comment: Once i searched about all these function (up, down, prev...) but didn't understand usage of completely. Can you send me any link where all these are specified clearly for better understanding.

Comment: @PuneetChawla It's not from Sencha but helps you to understand this functions: http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson5/2.cfm also you can search in the Sencha API too.